# Autodetect source for automake

Tags: c++, c, makefile, autotools, automake

I'm trying to do a Makefile.am who find all the dependency (c and cpp files) at runtime (make).

I test this command :

```
example_SOURCES=$(shell find . -type f | grep -E '\.c|\.cpp' | awk '{L[NR]=$$0} END {{for (i = 1; i <=NR-1;i++) print L[i]"\\"}; {print L[NR]}}')
```

The command works fine ( I have controlled with the add of a redirection in a file and the sources are fine).

But the makefile, doesn't use any sources :

```
gcc  -g -O2    -o example
```

How can I archive my objective for auto-founds all sources ?

p.s I have read that automake must know all sources at call, this is correct ? This can be an explanation why my script doesn't work.

More details : 
I have modify the Makefile generate and place an echo on example_sources and he contain all my files.

I have check the differences between the Makefile with my script and without and the main point is this part :

With script :

```
am_example_OBJECTS =
```

With manual dependency :

```
am_example_OBJECTS = ./main.$(OBJEXT)
```

He appear the automake need to know the sources files himself for generate the makefile.

Comment: try to print `example_SOURCES` and see if it has listed all of the source files.

Comment: For this kind of thing it's usually much simpler to use cmake.

Comment: @user35443 Is not a choice to use autotools is a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found a workaround,

I use a sed to change the Makefile.am during the configure.

```
# Source + dependency.
files=`find ./src/ -type f | grep -E '\.h$$|\.hpp$$|\.c$$|\.cpp$$' | sed 's/\/src//g'` 
sed -i '/.*_SOURCES.*/c\'"$soft"'_SOURCES = '"$files"'' src/Makefile.am
```

It's work fine, when we add sources, we just need to do ./configure to update the dependency list.